# Generality of a solution of a nonlinear PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-functions, fundamental-solution

Given the nonlinear PDE
$$
    \partial^2\phi+\phi^3=0
$$
I consider the characteristics $\xi=\kappa\cdot x$. Then I look for a solution in the form
$$
    \phi(x)=a\cdot\chi(\xi).
$$
Provided $\kappa^2=\frac{a}{2}$, I get the ODE defining of the Jacobi ${\rm sn}$ function and the final solution takes the form
$$
   \phi(x)=a\cdot{\rm sn}(a\xi/\sqrt{2}+b,-1).
$$
This solution has two arbitrary integration constants $a$ and $b$ that yield a family of solutions of the PDE we started from.

My question is this: How general could be considered such a solution for a nonlinear PDE? Is it a fundamental set from which all others could be obtained?

Answer (score 1):

That's not quite right.  The general solution to the ODE $y'' + y^3 = 0$
is $y = c \; \text{sn}(c(t - t_0)/\sqrt{2}, i)$.

Since this is a nonlinear equation, you **can't** take these as a "fundamental set":  other solutions will not be  linear combinations of these.

EDIT: For example, there will be radially symmetric solutions $y = f(r)$ which (in 3D) are solutions of the ODE

$$ f''(r) + \dfrac{2}{r} f'(r) + f(r)^3 = 0 $$

but I don't think this has closed-form solutions (other than $0$).

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert. Would this imply that other kind of solutions could be expected as solitons and so on? How could be exploited all the set of solutions of a nonlinear PDE failing the superposition principle?

Comment: I fixed the solution as you correctly pointed out.